# Get minimum and maximum value of expression by using brackets

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, parentheses

I have one-line expression without brackets, for instance `1+5*6-3`. We can use all operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). What I need to know? What is maximum and minimum value of expression when we can use brackets.

**Examples**

*1)*
Input: `1+5*6-3`
Output: `33 16`

*Explanation*: `33 = (((1+5)*6)-3)` | `16 = (1+(5*(6-3))`

*2)*
Input: `15*5-12-9`
Output: `72 -240`

*3)*
Input: `3*10*16-14-11*2`
Output: `954 -600`

*4)*
Input: `8-5*18+5-13+0*2+14-6*6+1`
Output: `7233 -13482`

*5)*
Input: `6+5-15*18+14-3-5-3-2-2*8-14+12`
Output: `11081 -4935`

*6)*
Input: `13-4*6*18+12+8-5*8-4+2+11*6+9-7+6*12*18+8-7+3*1-15*1-12*1-12-14+7-14*9*6`
Output: `74388962089190 -72949270802716`

And why I'm writing this post? I have fast algorithm, but it works for tests number `1`, `2`, `3`, but for `4`, `5`, `6` a get bad results. Why? Maybe you will see what I have done wrong. Here is my code:

```
public static long[] parenthesis(String expression, int start, int end) {
    if(resultStorage[start][end][2] == 1) 
        return resultStorage[start][end];

    if(isNumber(expression)) 
        return new long[] { Long.parseLong(expression), Long.parseLong(expression), 1 };

    long[] result = { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 1 };
    for(int i = 1; i < expression.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(i))) 
            continue;

        long[] left = parenthesis(expression.substring(0, i), start, start + i);
        long[] right = parenthesis(expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length()), start + i + 1, end);
        switch(expression.charAt(i)) {
            case '+' : result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[0] + right[0]);
                       result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[1] + right[1]); 
                       break;
            case '-' : result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[0] - right[0]);
                       result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[1] - right[1]); 
                       break;
            case '*' : result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[0] * right[0]);
                       result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[1] * right[1]); 
                       break;
            case '/' : if(right[0] != 0) 
                           result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[0] / right[0]);
                       if(right[1] != 0)
                           result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[1] / right[1]); 
                       break;
        }
    }

    resultStorage[start][end] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you plead add how resultStorage is defined and how paranthesis() is called in the beginning? Can you enable your code to print an explanation as you've given in test (1). And you are sure, the result you expect is the correct one (I'm sorry I can't overlook the result by watching the term)?

Comment: resultStorage is an array with results of recursion. `long[][][] resultStorage new long[expression.length()][expression.length() + 1][3]`. And parenthesis() is called like this: `parenthesis(expression, 0, expression.length())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write my own solution to understand the problem. My solution isn't that fast so there's no need to make it public. However, the reason why your solution doesn't work in all cases is, that it's not enough to use

```
new min = min left <op> min right
... analog for new max ...
```

because some min operands in combination with some operands (I suspect subtract and divide) produce a greater result and vice versa. Therefore all combinations of min/max left/right must be checked for the new min and new max value:

```
new min = min left <op> min right
new min = min left <op> max right
new min = max left <op> min right
new min = max left <op> max right
... analog for new max ...
```

So I introduced two nested loops into your code to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    parenthesis("1+5*6-3");
    parenthesis("15*5-12-9");
    parenthesis("3*10*16-14-11*2");
    parenthesis("8-5*18+5-13+0*2+14-6*6+1");
    parenthesis("6+5-15*18+14-3-5-3-2-2*8-14+12");
    parenthesis("13-4*6*18+12+8-5*8-4+2+11*6+9-7+6*12*18+8-7+3*1-15*1-12*1-12-14+7-14*9*6");
}

private static void parenthesis(String expression) {
    resultStorage = new long[100][100][100];
    long[] results = parenthesis(expression, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("=====> " + expression + " -> " + results[0] + "/" + results[1]);
}

private static long[][][] resultStorage;

public static long[] parenthesis(String expression, int start, int end) {
    if (resultStorage[start][end][2] == 1)
        return resultStorage[start][end];

    try {
        long parsedLong = Long.parseLong(expression);
        return new long[] { parsedLong, parsedLong, 1 };
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //
    }

    long[] result = { Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 1 };
    for (int i = 1; i < expression.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(i)))
            continue;
        long[] left = parenthesis(expression.substring(0, i), start, start + i);
        long[] right = parenthesis(expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length()), start + i + 1, end);
        for (int li = 0; li < 2; li++) {
            for (int ri = 0; ri < 2; ri++) {
                switch (expression.charAt(i)) {
                case '+':
                    result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[li] + right[ri]);
                    result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[li] + right[ri]);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[li] - right[ri]);
                    result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[li] - right[ri]);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[li] * right[ri]);
                    result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[li] * right[ri]);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if (right[ri] != 0)
                        result[0] = Math.min(result[0], left[li] / right[ri]);
                    if (right[ri] != 0)
                        result[1] = Math.max(result[1], left[li] / right[ri]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    resultStorage[start][end] = result;
    return result;
}
```

This produces exactly what you want:

```
=====> 1+5*6-3 -> 16/33
=====> 15*5-12-9 -> -240/72
=====> 3*10*16-14-11*2 -> -600/954
=====> 8-5*18+5-13+0*2+14-6*6+1 -> -13482/7233
=====> 6+5-15*18+14-3-5-3-2-2*8-14+12 -> -4935/11081
=====> 13-4*6*18+12+8-5*8-4+2+11*6+9-7+6*12*18+8-7+3*1-15*1-12*1-12-14+7-14*9*6 -> -72949270802716/74388962089190
```

**What I'm really interested in is, what this optimization does:**

```
if (resultStorage[start][end][2] == 1)
        return resultStorage[start][end];
```

The code works pretty well without resultStorage at all. But this recursion end condition makes it really fast without losing results. I'd be happy to hear how it works ...

EDIT: Okay, the optimization seems to terminate on already calculated results. However, as a sceptic I wanted to see the term with paranthesis to throw it into my calculator. So I did two more changes to the code: (1) Optimization by returning already calculated results for an expression, but with a HashMap Expression->Results (2) Evaluate the resulting term with paranthesis.

And here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    parenthesisOuter("1+5*6-3");
    parenthesisOuter("15*5-12-9");
    parenthesisOuter("3*10*16-14-11*2");
    parenthesisOuter("8-5*18+5-13+0*2+14-6*6+1");
    parenthesisOuter("6+5-15*18+14-3-5-3-2-2*8-14+12");
    parenthesisOuter("13-4*6*18+12+8-5*8-4+2+11*6+9-7+6*12*18+8-7+3*1-15*1-12*1-12-14+7-14*9*6");
    parenthesisOuter("1/0");
    parenthesisOuter("1/1-1");
}

private static void parenthesisOuter(String expression) {
    Object[] results = parenthesis(expression);
    System.out.println(expression + " -> " + results[MINVAL] + "=" + results[MINEXPR] + " "
            + results[MAXVAL] + "=" + results[MAXEXPR]);
}

private static Map<String, Object[]> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

private static final int MINVAL = 0;
private static final int MAXVAL = 1;
private static final int MINEXPR = 2;
private static final int MAXEXPR = 3;

public static Object[] parenthesis(String expression) {
    Object[] result = resultMap.get(expression);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }

    try {
        Long parsedLong = new Long(expression);
        return new Object[] { parsedLong, parsedLong, expression, expression };
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // go on, it's not a number
    }

    result = new Object[] { Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE, null, null };
    for (int i = 1; i < expression.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(i)))
            continue;
        Object[] left = parenthesis(expression.substring(0, i));
        Object[] right = parenthesis(expression.substring(i + 1, expression.length()));
        doOp(result, (Long) left[MINVAL], expression.charAt(i), (Long) right[MINVAL],
                (String) left[MINEXPR], (String) right[MINEXPR]);
        doOp(result, (Long) left[MINVAL], expression.charAt(i), (Long) right[MAXVAL],
                (String) left[MINEXPR], (String) right[MAXEXPR]);
        doOp(result, (Long) left[MAXVAL], expression.charAt(i), (Long) right[MINVAL],
                (String) left[MAXEXPR], (String) right[MINEXPR]);
        doOp(result, (Long) left[MAXVAL], expression.charAt(i), (Long) right[MAXVAL],
                (String) left[MAXEXPR], (String) right[MAXEXPR]);
    }

    resultMap.put(expression, result);
    return result;
}

private static void doOp(Object[] result, Long left, char op, Long right, String leftExpression,
        String rightExpression) {
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        setResult(result, left, op, right, left + right, leftExpression, rightExpression);
        break;
    case '-':
        setResult(result, left, op, right, left - right, leftExpression, rightExpression);
        break;
    case '*':
        setResult(result, left, op, right, left * right, leftExpression, rightExpression);
        break;
    case '/':
        if (right != 0) {
            setResult(result, left, op, right, left / right, leftExpression, rightExpression);
        }
        break;
    }
}

private static void setResult(Object[] result, Long left, char op, Long right, Long leftOpRight,
        String leftExpression, String rightExpression) {
    if (result[MINEXPR] == null || leftOpRight < (Long) result[MINVAL]) {
        result[MINVAL] = leftOpRight;
        result[MINEXPR] = "(" + leftExpression + op + rightExpression + ")";
    }
    if (result[MAXEXPR] == null || leftOpRight > (Long) result[MAXVAL]) {
        result[MAXVAL] = leftOpRight;
        result[MAXEXPR] = "(" + leftExpression + op + rightExpression + ")";
    }
}
```

which shows (the last two to see whether it's divide-by-zero-safe):

```
1+5*6-3 -> 16=(1+(5*(6-3))) 33=(((1+5)*6)-3)
15*5-12-9 -> -240=(15*((5-12)-9)) 72=((15*5)-(12-9))
3*10*16-14-11*2 -> -600=(3*(10*((16-14)-(11*2)))) 954=(((3*(10*16))-(14-11))*2)
8-5*18+5-13+0*2+14-6*6+1 -> -13482=(((((8-(5*(18+5)))-(13+0))*(2+14))-6)*(6+1)) 7233=(8-(5*(18+(((5-((13+0)*(2+14)))-6)*(6+1)))))
6+5-15*18+14-3-5-3-2-2*8-14+12 -> -4935=(6+((5-(15*((18+(14-((((3-5)-3)-2)-2)))*8)))-(14+12))) 11081=(6+(5-(15*((18+(14-((((3-5)-3)-2)-2)))*(8-(14+12))))))
13-4*6*18+12+8-5*8-4+2+11*6+9-7+6*12*18+8-7+3*1-15*1-12*1-12-14+7-14*9*6 -> -72949270802716=((((((((((13-4)*(6*(18+(12+8))))-5)*(((8-4)+(2+11))*(6+9)))-7)+6)*(12*(18+8)))-7)+3)*(1-(15*((1-(12*(((1-12)-(14+7))-14)))*(9*6))))) 74388962089190=((((13-4)*(6*(18+(12+8))))-5)*(((((8-((4+(2+11))*(6+9)))-(7+6))*(12*(18+8)))-(7+3))*(1-(15*((1-(12*(((1-12)-(14+7))-14)))*(9*6))))))
1/0 -> 9223372036854775807=null -9223372036854775808=null
1/1-1 -> 0=((1/1)-1) 0=((1/1)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you @yasd! So I'll answer your question, resultStorage is array with results of recursion. It contains start and end number, so if I have result in this array I return this from resultStorage instead of doing calculations one more time. Do you think it isn't necessaary?

Comment: I think I understand what you have done. Thanks. But what about time complexity? My goal is to make it minimum O(n^3).

Comment: @John Without that optimization I wasn't patient enough to wait for the result of the last test - same with my own solution - so it's absolutely necessary ... I just didn't got the clue how it works ;-) ... so I tried to do the same with a HashMap for already calculated results and added this to my answer. I cannot estimate the time complexity because I've no real idea how often the recursion starts - it's some sort of a permanently morphing tree ;-)

Comment: In pessimistic case we have n^2 sub-strings, where n is length of expression. So time complexity is minimum n^2, but in function we have some calculations so I think it's n^3 but I don't know how to explain this to be sure

Comment: @John I'm afraid, I've too less theoretical knowledge to answer this but to increase the exponent for the calculations feels to me to be a little overvaluation.

Comment: @John Besides the performance issue ... please feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if it was useful to you ;-)